# Arranging a word

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

This is the question :

In how many ways you can arrange the word AAABBCDEFG so that the first letter is A or E ?

I'm not sure if im doing this right. My plan is to take all the arrangments and reduce < br>
the number of options where A is the first letter and than reducing the options where 
E is the first letter and thus getting :

$$\frac{10!}{3!2!} -  \frac{7\cdot 9!}{3!2!} - \frac{9!}{3!2!}$$

sorry about the formating, still new at this, hope it's clear.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your formula is very confusing, but I notice a $3!$ in there - did you intend to have one of the letters repeat 3 times? Presently you have 2 As and 2 Bs.

Comment: Yes, one A was accidently erased, sorry.

Comment: I madean edit to your question to fix this and improve the formula formatting (also there was an obvious ! missing). Feel free to edit the question further - the 'edit' option is under the question tags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ways of arranging AAABBCDEFG without restriction I think you correctly identify as $\frac{10!}{3!2!}$ because of the repeated As (3) and Bs (2).

Fixing an A first gives you $\frac{9!}{2!2!}$ arrangements, and fixing an E first gives $\frac{9!}{3!2!}$ more arrangements. Total is therefore $$ \frac{9!(3+1)}{3!2!} =  \frac{4\cdot 9!}{3!2!} = \frac{9!}{3} = 120960$$

Comment: Where does that assumption come from?

Comment: @barakmanos I asked in the comments, because I saw there was a 3! in his attempt to solve.

Comment: Got it. I will fix mine then :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's another possibility:

Choose $6$ positions for BBCDFG, but excluding the first position.  ($9\choose 6$ ways.)

Arrange BBCDFG in these $6$ chosen positions: ($\frac{6!}{2}$ ways.)

Arrange AAAE in three remaining positions ($4$ ways.)

Total: $84\cdot 360\cdot 4=120960$ arrangements.

Comment: OP has changed the question from "AABBCDEFG" to "AAABBCDEFG".

Comment: Nice approach to the question

Comment: @barak manos: Thanks for pointing out the change in the question!

Answer (score 2):

The number of ways to arrange it so that the first letter is A:

Count the number of different permutations of AABBCDEFG:

$$\binom92\cdot\binom72\cdot\binom51\cdot\binom41\cdot\binom31\cdot\binom21\cdot\binom11=90720$$

---

The number of ways to arrange it so that the first letter is E:

Count the number of different permutations of AAABBCDFG:

$$\binom93\cdot\binom62\cdot\binom41\cdot\binom31\cdot\binom21\cdot\binom11=30240$$

---

Hence the total number of ways to arrange it so that the first letter is A or E:

Add the number of different permutations of AABBCDEFG and AAABBCDFG:

$$90720+30240=120960$$

Comment: When we arrage it so that the first letter is A. we actually dont really care if there is another A already there ? I thought i should divide it by two because of repeats

Comment: @MattG: That's when you calculate the probability. You asked for the number of arrangements.

Comment: @MattG: Also, this answer is for the word "AABBCDEFG" (which is how you originally posted the question).

Comment: @MattG: This should give you a general method for solving this type of questions (for example, if the number of occurrences of each letter was much higher).